# Integration of "angular-cron-jobs" with the latest Angular 2 Applications

Tags: angularjs, angular, cron, ionic2

Anytime I import this module "Angular-cron-jobs" in the Ionic 2 / Angular 2 using the ngModule decorator, I get the

"angular is not a function".

Is there a way around this or is there an angular2 version of this module?

"angular-cron-jobs" is a cron job UI directive from https://github.com/angular-cron-jobs but I noticed it's written in angular 1.*

How can I get it to work or is there a similar module doing the same thing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us your code, can't debug what we can't see

Comment: My code is simple

`import * as cron from 'angular-cron-jobs';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-create-campaign',
  templateUrl: 'create-campaign.html'
})
export class CreateCampaignPage {}`

And the template page is as follows

`<cron-selection ng-model="myOutput"></cron-selection>`